# Lists containers in c++ , using a list in a class

Tags: c++, list, templates, stl, containers

I am creating this template Queue using a list. I don't understand what the error is about the list part. When I type listObject.push_back(), the program says that no member functions are located. Thanks in advance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>


using namespace std;


template<class T, class E>
class Queue{

public:

// Creates a Queue with an initial capacity of 10
Queue();
//Creates a Queue object with an initial capacity of size cap
Queue(int cap);
//adds item to the end of the queue
void add(T item);
//returns true if the queue is empty
bool isEmpty() const;
//removes the front item from the qeue
T remove();
//Provide a copy of the object that is first in the queue
T first() const;
//updates the item in the front of the queue
void updateFirst(T item);
//output all information currently stored in the queue
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Queue<E>& obj)

 private:

list<E> listObject;
int capacity;
};

 template<class T, class E>
 Queue<T,E>::Queue()
 {
capacity = 10;
 }

 template<class T, class E>
 Queue<T,E>::Queue(int cap)
 {

capacity = cap;
 }

 template<class T, class E>
  void Queue<T,E>::add(E item)
 {

listObject.push_back( item );

 }
```

Comment: Well, you *are* pushing a `T` onto a list of `E`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list object is defined to be a `list<E>`, but you're trying to push_back an object of type `T`.

Comment: Thanks. But even though I corrected it, when I type listObject. the program says no member functions available.

Comment: The "program" is the compiler, and you should paste the exact error message.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say "the program says no member functions available". I copied your code into a file, fixed a couple of syntax errors, and then it compiled w/o error.